# Where tsserver logs are located?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I added this setting

```
"typescript.tsserver.log": "verbose"
```

Now where are the logs located? I've searched in `/var/log` and `~/.config/Code/...` with no success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be located in: `~/.config/Code/logs/**/tsserver.log`

To open the file:

1. Press <kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Type `Open TS server log`
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: The funny thing is that I had found the same path and have answered to my own question, but some clever guys downvoted me because they probably have another path in their system, so I deleted my answer. Anyway, I am going to accept yours one.

Answer (score 0):

## As of 2024, macOS 14.2, VSCode 1.85:

- `cmd-shift-p` > `Open Logs Folder`
- inside that folder, go to `window<XXX>/exthost/vscode.typescript-language-features/tsserver-log-<id>/tsserver.log`

[image: tsserver logs macos 14.2]

To copy the full file path: select the interesting `tsserver.log` file -> right click -> `Copy`.

[image: copy tsserver path]

Then in your terminal: `code <cmd-v>` to open the logs in VSCode.

Overall the full path path is:

```
/Users/<yourname>/Library/Application Support/Code/logs/<timestamp>/window<N>/exthost/vscode.typescript-language-features/tsserver-log-<hash>/tsserver.log`
```

❗️ Note the space in `Application Support` folder name; so from command line, you either need to escape it as `Application\ Support`, or quote the path and NOT have the `\` escape before the space.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.86.2, the command "Open TS server log" is not shown by default.

You'll need to go to the setting, "typscript > tsserver: log" and change from "off" to "verbose" or "normal".
Once done, the command "Open TS server log" is back.

Another option to get the path is by selecting "typescript" in the "OUTPUT" section. It shows something like: `[info] <semantic> Log file: /Users/...` with the full path.